# Database for a multi-user RPG

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a Flash turn-based RPG to practice OOP (who doesn't :P) I have a pretty good setup with the Weapons, Items, and all that Jazz. Though I'm currently considering how I will make my characters.

Currently I have an `player` and `enemy` class that extends the `battler` class.

```
     Battler
      /  \
     /    \
 Player  Enemy
```

My `player` class has some functions that initialize the player itself, adding the graphics and all that. My `party` class calls on `player`, passing a paramater like so: player.setup(1) with 1 being the playerID.

To Clarify this is my player pseudocode:

```
{   setup(player_id)
    player =  **??????player_id??????????**
    name = player.name
    character_name = player.character_name
    character_index = player.character_index
    weapon_id = player.returnWeapon
 /*---------
    armor1_id = player.returnArmor //increase for other body parts
 ----------*/
    level = player.level
}
```

My question, or more of a problem is how I will store the player data. I need to have many players as this is a game with many players in a party.

How will I actually use something like `player.returnArmor` ? Because when I do that it just calls a function, and it will not know who that player is (I guess I could use parameters, like `player.returnArmor(player)` but I think there is a better way to do this.

Any language is welcome, but just so you don't use assembly language as an example ;), C++, Actionscript 3, Ruby, and/or Java is fine. Please Help Me! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In AS3 you can have static and instance functions. If you call `player.returnarmor()`, you're calling a static function. You want to have an instance function, and call it for the instance of the player whose armor value you want.

If you have a few (<4) characters, you can just have named variables for each, but more than 3 or 4 and you should just have an array or other container for them.

```
var mainProtagonist:player;
var spunkySidekick:player;
var whiteMage:player;
var players:Array = new Array();
players.push(mainProtagonist);
players.push(spunkySidekick);
players.push(whiteMage);
```

Then to get a player's armor...we'll say you want the spunky sidekick's armor:

```
players[1].returnarmor();
// or
spunkySidekick.returnarmor();
```

You might have an array of all the players in existence, as well as another array, when used in battle, with just the players in the current party/battle. That way your enemies can target players at random, and only from those currently in the battle.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth considering using an entity system, where each item in the game is treated as a collection of unrelated properties (location, velocity, bitmap/mesh) which can be managed separately. This tends to make the hard problems easier (scalability, synchronisation, storage).

- http://www.tomseysdavies.com/2011/01/23/entity-systems/
- http://www.richardlord.net/blog/what-is-an-entity-framework
- http://www.richardlord.net/blog/why-use-an-entity-framework

Comment: yeah entity is cool, but depending on your required transaction speed you may want to consider a nosql solution like Table Storage, MongoDB or RavenDB.  the cool thing is you may want to look into as well is MVC4 new API tools. they make it really easy to scaffold out your player models in an easy to use API.